# How to load a webpage after spooky.js is initialized

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs, spookyjs

Is it possible to chain missions to spookyjs after initialization? Something like this:

```
Spooky = require('spooky');
var spooky = new Spooky({
    child: {
        transport: 'http'
    },
    casper: {
        logLevel: 'debug',
        verbose: true
    }
}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        e = new Error('Failed to initialize SpookyJS');
        e.details = err;
        throw e;
    }

    spooky.start(
        'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spooky_the_Tuff_Little_Ghost');
    spooky.run();
});

spooky.thenOpen('http://google.com', function () {
    console.log('bla');
});

spooky.on('console', function (line) {
    console.log(line);
});
```

But when I do this I get this error:

```
TypeError: Object # has no method 'thenOpen'
```

Comment: You can put the `thenOpen` call directly behind the `start` call, but I guess you're asking something else. Why don't you describe your use case and what you want to achieve instead of showing some arbitrary limitation of spookyjs.

Comment: I need to open a page in spookyjs, then run sum code outside spookyjs context, and then open another page. I don't want to re-initialize spookyjs for the mission, but use an existing process of phantomjs.

Comment: Hi someone235, why don´t to the page calls within one spookyJS session- As Artjom mentioned, the thenOpen method will help you.